# How do you determine if a number is prime or composite?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any way to decipher, manually of course, whether a (large enough) number is a prime?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Manually, or mechanically? :-)

Answer (score 11):

If someone gives you a random large number, the last thing you want to do is perform a deterministic primality test -- it's very likely to be composite.  Firstly, you should perform:

- trial division and
- [Fermat's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test).

These can be performed using PFGW (from http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/primeform/).  You might even want to perform a stronger pseudo-primality test.

Once these tests have been passed, then you should be somewhat confident you have a prime.  If you're happy with a probable prime, then you can stop.  Otherwise, you'll need a proof.  [Curiously, if sufficiently many probabilistic primality tests have been performed, the probability that the number is composite can be less than the probability of a random error occurring in a "proof" of its primality.]

If your number has no particularly special form you can exploit, then your best hope is [elliptic curve primality proving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality_proving) (see [here](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=27) for ECPP records).  You could use [Primo](http://www.ellipsa.eu/) or [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

However, if your candidate prime happens to have a special form, then there are various deterministic primality proofs you could use.  For example, the [Lucas-Lehmer test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) (cf. [GIMPS](http://www.mersenne.org/)), Proth's test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth's_theorem), [Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test).  In fact, these tests are great if you're the type of person who aspires to finding a [top-5000 prime](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/home.php) (something I used to do: see [my profile](http://primes.utm.edu/bios/page.php?id=776)).

Again, before using these tests, you should perform trial division.  If you're looking for primes that can be proved by the latter two tests, you will probably find [NewPGen](http://primes.utm.edu/programs/NewPGen/) invaluable.

Comment: "If someone gives you a random large number, the last thing you want to do is perform a deterministic primality test -- it's very likely to be composite." - Heh. :D +1! @Sachindra: without a computer to assist, it might take you quite a while to verify if some random large number you were given is prime!

Comment: Hehe, I was tempted to mention that proving primality "manually" would be quite difficult.  Re: $2^{127}-1$ "This may stand forever as the largest prime number proven by hand." (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas).